# Typhoon : wire circular dependency in storyboard created view controller

Tags: ios, uistoryboard, typhoon

I am loading view controllers from TyphoonStoryboard and have a definition for the class which works fine, several properties are injected with no problems. However one of the properties is a view which itself has a delegate property which I want to be the view controller instance. When the view comes to set the delegate property it tries to create a new instance of the view controller instead of using the instance which has been created by the storyboard. How can I make the delegate property use the current instance of the view controller? My definitions look something like this:

```
- (id)viewController
{
  return [TyphoonDefinition withClass:[MyViewController class]     
    configuration:^(TyphoonDefinition *definition) {
    [definition injectProperty:@selector(view) with:[self myView]];
  }];
}

- (id)myView
{
    return [TyphoonDefinition withClass:[MyView class]         
    configuration:^(TyphoonDefinition *definition) {
        [definition injectProperty:@selector(delegate) 
           with:[self viewController]];
    }];
}
```

From what I can see the view controller can never be used a reference as it doesn't added a shared reference anywhere and Typhoon has no option but to instantiate a new one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was not supported prior to Typhoon 2.3.4. Prior to this version, objects created outside of Typhoon did not participate in scope pools. Therefore, its not possible to wire `delegate` to `viewController` with Typhoon, but you could wire in Interface Builder or use a `performAfterInjections` callback.

As of 2.3.4, objects instantiated outside of Typhoon, but subsequently injected, participate in the scope pools, therefore circular dependencies work as expected.